# Django - Modificar widget Select lista personalizada?

Tags: django, django-forms

Muy buenas , quisiera saber como modificar mi select con una consulta modificada , me hago explicar...

## models.py

```
class Equipo(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    color = RGBColorField()
    torneo = models.ForeignKey(Torneo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.nombre)
```

## forms.py

```
class Equipo_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Equipo
        fields =[
            'nombre',
            'color',
            'torneo',
        ]

        labels={
            'nombre':'Nombre del Equipo',
            'color':'Color Uniforme',
            'torneo':'Participar Torneo',
        }

        widgets={
            'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'color': RGBColorField(),
            'torneo': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

De esta manera me muestra en mi widget forms.Select Todos los torneos existentes sin importar el usuario , quiero que me muestre la lista de torneos creados por el usuario.

Tengo una vista de tipo listView donde muestra los torneos segun el usuario logueado esta asi:

## views.py

```
class Torneo_ListView(ListView):    
    template_name = 'torneos/torneo_listar.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Torneo.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

alguna forma de filtrar en mi models.select una lista de torneos segun el usuario.

Sé que con el "chouce" son los valores a mostrar pero no se como integrar el usuario a la consulta

```
widgets={
    'torneo': forms.Select(chouse=Torneos.objects.filter(user=¿??)attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

que deberia ir ahi , eh intentado "(user=self.request.user)" igual que en la ListView pero obviamente no funciona.

Consulte en la documentacion de la clase Select https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#Select

no entiendo muy bien como aplicarlo , Antemano pido disculpas si la solucion es facil y no supe arreglarlo.

## SOLUCION:

## views.py

```
class Equipo_CreateView(CreateView):
    model = Equipo
    template_name = "torneos/equipo_crear.html"
    form_class = Equipo_Form
    success_url = reverse_lazy('torneos:equipo_crear')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(Equipo_CreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'request': self.request})

    def form_valid(self, form_class):
        form_class.instance.user_id = self.request.user.id
        return super(Equipo_CreateView, self).form_valid(form_class)
```

## forms.py

```
class Equipo_Form(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Equipo_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['torneo'].queryset =  Torneo.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    class Meta:
        model = Equipo
        fields =[
            'nombre',
            'color',
            'torneo',
        ]

        labels={
            'nombre':'Nombre del Equipo',
            'color':'Color Uniforme',
            'torneo':'Participar Torneo',
        }


        widgets={
            'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'color': RGBColorField(),
        }
```

Comment: no olvides retornar en el metodo `get_form_kwargs` la variable kwargs, es decir poner al final un `return kwargs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando trabajas con `select` que vienen de un modelo, no es necesario que uses un widget `Select`, Django un día creó un widget mágico llamado `ModelChoiceField` el cual se encarga de renderizar un queryset haciendolo `select` y `options`, Dicho widget, ya viene por default cuando generas un `ModelForm`, por lo que no necesitas especificarlo. Es decir, en tu archivo de forms.py, en la linea donde pones el widget de torneo a un select, podrías eliminarla y añadir lo siguiente:

```
...
def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['torneo'].queryset = Torneo.objects.filter(user=request.user)
...
```

Y lo unico que debes de tener en cuenta es que ahora cada vez que uses en tu vista el formulario, debes agregarle la petición, de esta forma:

```
class Equipo_CreateView(CreateView):
    ...
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
       kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
       kwargs.update({'request': self.request})
       return kwargs
...
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Cualquier duda, comenta.

Comment: Bro aun asi me sigue listando todos los torneos existentes , no los filtra segun el usuario, que estara mal ? 
German para la view de crear el equipo no utilizo una funcion , sino la clase CreateView

Comment: Ahh ok, es una clase, de que clase heredas de CreateView?? ya te corrijo

Comment: Bro, edite la pregunta añadiendo la CreateView

Comment: editada la respuesta

Comment: Exception Value: 
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'

Me da este error..

Comment: @jhonperez editado, me faltaba llamar el super, en la primera linea del __init__ del formulario

Comment: me sigue apareciendo el mismo error, ya edite la pregunta agregando ahora como tengo el codigo :v

Comment: solo para verificar, y ver tu problema, asegurate que el metodo __init__ que  escribiste en tus forms.py, NO esté indentado luego de la clase Meta, si no de tu otra clase, para asegurarte que no te pase, muevelo al principio de la clase, antes de poner tu clase Meta y al mismo nivel de la clase Meta

Comment: Listo Bro muchas gracias , en la pregunta coloque la respuesta. De donde se baso para la respuesta , documentacion?

Comment: en realidad es conocer python, la documentacion de python